# Django Rest Framework - return Response(serializer.data) image field get null instead of the url

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I set an 'ImageField' in the model, using postman to post data. The image uploaded successfully. However, when my view returns serializers.data, the image field is null, which is supposed to be the URL of the image.  Does anyone have any ideas? I appreciate it so much.
This is the response

```
{
    "user": 7,
    "category": "2018",
    "cover": null,
    "name": "Louisville"
}
```

This is my model

```
class Journey(models.Model):
    def user_directory_path(self, filename):
        return 'media/journey_cover/{0}/{1}'.format(self.user_id, filename)

    user = models.ForeignKey(to=UserProfile, related_name="journeys", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=50)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=50)
```

My serializer:

```
class JourneySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=UserProfile.objects.all())
    cover = serializers.ImageField(use_url=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Journey
        fields = ['user', 'category', 'cover', 'name']
```

My View

```
class JourneyList(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrReadOnly, permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser, FormParser]

    def post(self, request):
        print(request.content_type)
        serializer = JourneySerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            journey = serializer.create(serializer.validated_data)
            journey.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: try altering `upload_to` to see if the error is caused by your method

Comment: change it to a directory just for testing purpose

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed Thank you for your advice. However, I tried to change upload_to='media', the result is same.

Comment: don't forget the slash 'media/', tell me if it"s the same error

Comment: Hey Ahmed, I tried to add '/' at the end, but the result is same. It's not an error. When I use 'Get' method, It returns Json and the 'cover' field serialized to the url, which is good. Just when I post a json the 'cover' in serializer.data got null

Answer (score 1):

in the url.py file you have to add

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
   ..... // your urls

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
if settings.DEBUG:
        urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                              document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and in the setting file

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```